# blocks aggregation in ObjectPageSubsection + OData thee levels deep

Tags: data-binding, odata, sapui5

I'm trying to build some sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout in my app using three levels of my OData service.
When I try to bind the "blocks" aggregation as a '{path: 'node', template: oTemplate}' it does not complete the bindings in the template, and the console logs many errors.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "sap_belize" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
   src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
   data-sap-ui-theme='sap_belize_plus'
   data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m, sap.uxap'
   data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>


  <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->

  <!-- define a new (simple) View type as an XmlView
   - using data binding for the Button text
   - binding a controller method to the Button's "press" event
   - also mixing in some plain HTML
   note: typically this would be a standalone file -->

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="my.own.controller">
   <App>
    <Page id="MyPage"/>
   </App>
  </mvc:View> 
 </script>


  <script>
   // define a new (simple) Controller type
   sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {

    // implement an event handler in the Controller
    onInit: function(){
     var oPage = this.getView().byId("MyPage");
     oPage.bindElement("/Employees(9)")
     var oOPL = new sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout({
      showTitleOnHeader: true,
      showTitleInHeaderContent: true,
      headerTitle: new sap.uxap.ObjectPageHeader({
       isObjectTitleAlwaysVisible: false,
       isObjectSubtitleAlwaysVisible: false,
       objectTitle: "{FirstName} {LastName}",
       objectSubtitle: "{Title}",
       objectImageShape: "Circle",
       objectImageURI: "https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/uxap/images/imageID_275314.png",
      }),
      headerContent: new sap.m.VBox({
       items: [
        new sap.m.Text({text: "{Address}"}),
        new sap.m.Text({text: "{City} ({Region})"}),
        new sap.m.Text({text: "{Country}"}),
       ]
      }),
      sections: [
       new sap.uxap.ObjectPageSection({
        title: "Orders",
        subSections: {
         path: "Orders",         
         template: new sap.uxap.ObjectPageSubSection({
          title: "Order ID: {OrderID}",
                                        blocks: {
                                            path: "Customer",
                                            template: this.getBlocks()
                                        }
         })
        }
       })
      ]      
     });
     oPage.addContent(oOPL);     
    },
              
                getBlocks: function(){
                    var oInput = new sap.m.Input({value: "{CompanyName}"})
                    //oInput.bindElement("Customer");
                    return oInput;
                }
   });
 
 
 
   /*** THIS IS THE "APPLICATION" CODE ***/
   // instantiate the View
   var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above

   // create a Model and assign it to the View
   var uri = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc"; // local proxy for cross-domain access
   var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(uri, {
    maxDataServiceVersion: "2.0",
                useBatch: true
   }); 
   myView.setModel(oModel);
   // put the View onto the screen
   myView.placeAt('content');

  </script>
 
 </head>
 <body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here the Snippet: https://jsbin.com/sikihujuha/edit?html,output

I workaround it doing a element binding each time the template control is built. But it calls the service one time per entry instead of creating the binding and call all the properties in a batch request.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "sap_belize" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
   src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
   data-sap-ui-theme='sap_belize_plus'
   data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m, sap.uxap'
   data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>


  <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->

  <!-- define a new (simple) View type as an XmlView
   - using data binding for the Button text
   - binding a controller method to the Button's "press" event
   - also mixing in some plain HTML
   note: typically this would be a standalone file -->

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="my.own.controller">
   <App>
    <Page id="MyPage"/>
   </App>
  </mvc:View> 
 </script>


  <script>
   // define a new (simple) Controller type
   sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {

    // implement an event handler in the Controller
    onInit: function(){
     var oPage = this.getView().byId("MyPage");
     oPage.bindElement("/Employees(9)")
     var oOPL = new sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout({
      showTitleOnHeader: true,
      showTitleInHeaderContent: true,
      headerTitle: new sap.uxap.ObjectPageHeader({
       isObjectTitleAlwaysVisible: false,
       isObjectSubtitleAlwaysVisible: false,
       objectTitle: "{FirstName} {LastName}",
       objectSubtitle: "{Title}",
       objectImageShape: "Circle",
       objectImageURI: "https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/uxap/images/imageID_275314.png",
      }),
      headerContent: new sap.m.VBox({
       items: [
        new sap.m.Text({text: "{Address}"}),
        new sap.m.Text({text: "{City} ({Region})"}),
        new sap.m.Text({text: "{Country}"}),
       ]
      }),
      sections: [
       new sap.uxap.ObjectPageSection({
        title: "Orders",
        subSections: {
         path: "Orders",         
         template: new sap.uxap.ObjectPageSubSection({
          title: "Order ID: {OrderID}",
                                        blocks: this.getBlocks()
         })
        }
       })
      ]      
     });
     oPage.addContent(oOPL);     
    },
              
                getBlocks: function(){
                    //var oInput = new sap.m.Input({value: "{Customer/CompanyName}"})
                    var oInput = new sap.m.Input({value: "{CompanyName}"})
                    oInput.bindElement("Customer");
                    return [oInput];
                }
   });
 
 
 
   /*** THIS IS THE "APPLICATION" CODE ***/
   // instantiate the View
   var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above

   // create a Model and assign it to the View
   var uri = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc"; // local proxy for cross-domain access
   var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(uri, {
    maxDataServiceVersion: "2.0",
                useBatch: true
   }); 
   myView.setModel(oModel);
   // put the View onto the screen
   myView.placeAt('content');

  </script>
 
 </head>
 <body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here workaround: https://jsbin.com/zajacodoce/edit?html,output

Any Idea to improve this?

Thank you and regards,
Rafael Lopez

Answer (score 0):

Good, I found one error in my code of the workaround. I didn't expand the first element binding properly, it should be: $expand=Orders/Customer
I guess it was a typo from my tests.

Anyway the first snippet does not work, seems like the Blocks aggregation includes another "$expand" parameter to the url, and the errors appear in the console